# Best Methods for Dynamically Creating New Objects

Tags: c++, vector, dynamic-data

I'm looking for a method to dynamically create new class objects during runtime of a program. So far what I've read leads me to believe it's not easy and normally reserved for more advanced program requirements.

What I've tried so far is this:

```
// create a vector of type class
vector<class_name> vect;

// and use push_back (method 1)
vect.push_back(*new Object);

//or use for loop and [] operator (method 2)
vect[i] = *new Object;
```

neither of these throw errors from the compiler, but I'm using ifstream to read data from a file and dynamically create the objects... the file read is taking in some weird data and occasionally reading a memory address, and it's obvious to me it's due to my use/misuse of the code snippet above.

The file read code is as follows:

```
// in main
ifstream fileIn
fileIn.open( fileName.c_str() );

// passes to a separate function along w/ vector
loadObjects (fileIn, vect);

void loadObjects (ifstream& is, vector<class_name>& Object) {
    int data1, data2, data3;
    int count = 0;
    string line;

    if( is.good() ){
        for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {    
            is >> data1 >> data2 >> data3;
            if (data1 == 0) {
                vect.push_back(*new Object(data2, data3) )
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: HAHAHA! @KerrekSB, that's awesome! It's for an assignment so I'm stuck with this garbage... for now.

Comment: `*new Object` is a memory leak - never do that. `vector` takes care of dynamic allocation for you, so `vect.push_back(Object());` is all you need.

Comment: Can you post your `class` definition? you know class is c++ keyword, you can't use it in vector<class>

Comment: It's not that way in the real thing, here's the pastebin: http://pastebin.com/0qJtcxxh

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you absolutely have to use pointers (your objects store large data sets internally) then you should change your code to:

```
// create a vector of type class
vector<class*> vect;

// and use push_back (method 1)
vect.push_back(new Object);

//or use for loop and [] operator (method 2)
vect[i] = new Object;
```

Keep in mind that you'll have to `delete` your objects at some point.

Answer (score 4):

```
vector<Object> vect;
vect.push_back(Object()); // or vect.emplace_back();
```

That's it. That is the correct way, period. Any problems you are describing with reading objects from a file are a seperate matter, and we'd need to see that code in order to help you figure out what is wrong.

If you need polymorphism, then use a smart pointer:

```
vector<unique_ptr<Base>> vect;
vect.emplace_back(new Derived);
```

If you are, for some reason, constrained from using smart pointers, the old fashioned, error prone way to do it is like this:

```
vector<Base *> vect;
vect.push_back(new Derived);
....
for (int i=0; i<vect.size(); ++i)
{
    delete vect[i];
    vect[i] = NULL;
}
```

This is, of course, not exception safe.

Comment: Alternatively, `vect.emplace_back();`, or `vect.resize(vect.size() + 1);`, to avoid the awkward temporary... but anyway +1 for what seems to be the only sane answer.

Comment: @frankV: Well, I know that's not your actual code, because `vector<class>` cannot be legal, because `class` is a keyword, and cannot be the name of a class.

Comment: Sorry @BenjaminLindley I wrote it that way for the sake of brevity. Here's a pastebin of the full application file. You'll have to trust me that all class headers are sound. http://pastebin.com/0qJtcxxh

Comment: @frankV: The code in that link looks nothing like the sample code in your question.  But anyway, that's beside the point.  Your original question was about how to dynamically create objects.  I've shown you that.  If you have another question, make a separate post.

Answer (score 1):

```
vector<classType> vect;
```

declares vector container which contains type of `classType`, but you are adding `a pointer to classType` into vect, which will make compiler unhappy indeed.

If you need to present object's `polymorphism` in vector container, you need to store pointer to object, change your vect type to:

```
vector<std::shared_ptr<classType> > vect;
```

Comment: @frankV in your case, you need to use object polymorphism, you need to store pointer in vector instead of object.

Answer (score 0):

Declaring dynamic objects uses the following format:

```
TypeName * Name = new TypeName
```

you're going a little to fast with your vector, what you need to do is create a new object of class Object, THEN push it into the vector.

```
Object * MyObj = new Object //allocate space for new object
vect.push_back(MyObj) //push back new object
```

REMEMBER to delete what ever you allocate, which means looping through each element at the end  to delete its member:

```
for(int i = 0; i < vectLen; i++) //probably will be replaced with iterators for vectors
{
    delete vect[i];
}
```

**read up on dynamic allocation more in depth [here](http://www.cs.fsu.edu/~myers/cgs4406/notes/dma.html)**

Comment: It's actually creating objects of a sub-class, and each pass through the input file can create multiples of each. So it has to be completely dynamic. I know to delete each after they're used, but thanks for the reminder.